# Link in HTML to go to .aspx page

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a html page index.html that link to a page default.aspx, both are in my root directory and working fine. The index.html contains a flash object that contains the link to default.aspx. However I want to replace the index page to a normal html page with no flash and I want to move the location of default.aspx to a secure directory. When I do this the default.aspx page does not load, instead I get an error message:

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Only Content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains Content controls.

Source Error:

Line 224:
Line 225:
Line 226:
Source File: /mcc/default.aspx    Line: 226

Does anyone know what I have to do to resolve this

Comment: please show us code ! how do you expect us to guess the answer without more details ?

Comment: my guess is you just dragged and dropped your aspx page into a new folder without adjusting something like namespace in the codebehind and/or inherit in the page header

Comment: Yeah I did just drag and drop, thats where I must have gone wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my guess, you might be using a "Master Page" and you have given "html/body" tags in the aspx page which is not allowed. So, either use a master page and have a ContentPlaceHolder in the aspx page or remove the master page and have everything in you aspx page directly. My suggestion would be to go with a master page.

Hope this Helps!!